# Vacuum packed halibut fillets

Tags: frozen

I just found a  lg box of vacuum packed halibut fillets in my freezer. Been there at least 8 yrs. safe to eat?  Worth a lot of money!

Comment: The one difference versus the comprehensive Q&A linked by @Tetsujin is that these are vacuum packed. Given that if frozen properly it is not a food safety issue but a food quality issues, the vacuum packed (if intact) protects against the water loss that degrades quality aka freezer burn. Not sure about protein integrity.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Your question will be closed as a duplicate of our general "is this still good" generic answer, because ultimately the answer is always "depends on circumstances and your tolerance of risk".  Sorry about that, but we get this general type of question 10X per day.